# Yii2 - How to render the index view plus the create view all in the same page

Tags: view, render, yii2

**Greetings,**

So far i have made Yii2 applications always rendering one view per action in some Controller.

But now i need to render 2 view files, the `index` and the `create` in the same screen.

In Yii1.xx there was `renderPartial()`, and in Yii2 now there is `render()` as substitute but don't know how to use it. I know the syntax is somewhat like `app/Controller::render()` but it doesn't ring a bell to me.

**My actionIndex in my SiteController is:**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new TubeSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute('tube/index'), [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

**This action loads the tube/index page as the starting page of the app. I want to join in the load the create action. Is it possible -> two php files rendering in the same screen at statup.**

**many thanks...**

Comment: I don't get the point of mark with -1, one question that is important to me to be solved. I have done research in the subject, and i'm already working on it, but simply could not get so far a solution that works as i need. So i wrote this post to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED IT BY MYSELF.

SITECONTROLLER CODE:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute('tube/index'));
}
```

TUBECONTROLLER CODE:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new TubeSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model = new Tube();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->save();
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

**This way the index and create view are together in the same page and every thing works ok.**

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what you are actually trying to achieve, so I'll propose two solutions, based on two very different scenarios. In both scenarios, you will need to configure the `action` parameter of your form to point to `tube/create`, otherwise your form will not submit properly.

**Scenario 1** - You want the `tube/index` view to be rendered when your user visits `site/index`

Since the view `tube/index` seems to be about creating new models, I'll call it tube/create instead, for simplicity.

Redirecting from your index page would seem to me to be bad practice. It will double the load on your server, and the user may be confused as to why they are being redirected. The simplest way to achieve this would be just to render the `tube/create` view in the `index` action of your site controller, like this;

```
public function actionIndex(){

    $searchModel = new TubeSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model = new Tube();

    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $model->save();
    return $this->render('@app/views/tube/create', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

**Scenario 2** - You want to render two views on the same page, one to view the results of some kind of search, and the other to create a new model. This is what you might have used `renderPartial()` for in Yii1. you would do it like this;

I'm sticking with rendering tube/create in the site/index action.

```
public function actionIndex(){

    $searchModel = new TubeSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model = new Tube();

    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $model->save();
    return $this->render('//tube/index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

You would then just render the two separate partial views in your `tube/index` view file, like this.

```
/** tube/index **/
echo $this->render('//tube/view', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,]);
echo $this->render('//tube/create', [
    'model' => $model]
);
```

The two scenarios assume that your view files are located in the `views/tube` folder, and that you have already loaded the necessary models with a `use` statement at the top of the controller file.